# awk how to concat number with strings

Tags: awk, concatenation

I am trying to append some text after each line of a file. 
I have a file that each line consist of a number:

123

123

123

if I run `awk '{print $1"a"}'` myfile.txt I get:

a23

a23

a23

I am pretty sure it is because of the number in the file. I ran it with other files with regular lines this problem doesn't happen. But I couldn't find anywhere talking about this.

I also tried `awk'{char=$1"a";print char}'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your input file lines each end in control-M before the carriage return, probably because it was created in Windows. Use:

```
cat -v myfile.txt
awk '{print $1"a"}' myfile.txt | cat -v
```

to see them and then run `dos2unix` or similar on the input file to remove them then try your script again.

Comment: +1.  Alternatively, `dos2unix` can be avoided by adding `\r` as a field separator: `awk -F'\r' '{print $1"a"}'`

Comment: Thank you guys so much. This worked! I tried to search for the ^M in vim, but it says no pattern found so I didn't realize the problem.

Comment: `vim` will hide the `^M` because it auto-senses whether a file is dos or unix format and adjusts accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

It's very strange!  Please try

```
awk '{print $0 "a"}' file
```